# Using a header file in one code file and then vice versa?

Tags: c++

So I've got a bit of a problem (well two but they're unrelated to each other).

I have two headers that look as follows:

Game.h

```
#ifndef INIT_GAME_H
#define INIT_GAME_H

#include <deps/deps.h>

#include <handlers/RenderHandler.h>

class Game {
    private:
        RenderHandler* renderHandler; /* <-- This is line 32 in my actual header */

    public:
        Game() {};
        ~Game() {};

        int initialise();
        void handleEvents();
        void update();
        void render();
        void clean();
}; // class Game
#endif // INIT_GAME_H
```

RenderHandler.h

```
#ifndef HANDLERS_RENDERHANDLER_H
#define HANDLERS_RENDERHANDLER_H

#include <init/Game.h>

class RenderHandler {
    private:
        Game* game;

    public:
        RenderHandler() {};
        ~RenderHandler() {};

        void initialise(Game* game);
        void render();
}; // class RenderHandler
#endif // HANDLERS_RENDERHANDLER_H
```

But the above gives me an error during compilation:

```
game.h(32): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
game.h(32): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
game.h(32): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

As you've probably guessed, I'm trying to store `Game`'s instance in `RenderHandler` and vice versa. I'm probably doing it completely the wrong way but I can't figure why it's not working.

Also, all `;` are in their right places prior to line 32 in my header file.

EDIT:

after doing the suggested forward declaration, I get the following error (now in RenderHandler.cpp file).

```
Error: pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed
```

This is what my code file looks like

RenderHandler.cpp

```
#include <handlers/RenderHandler.cpp>

void RenderHandler::initialise(Game* game) {
    this->game = game;
}

void RenderHandler::render() {
    glfwSwapBuffers(game->getPrimaryWindow());
}
```

Comment: use forward declaration in the files

Answer (score 5):

Use forward declaration :

```
#ifndef HANDLERS_RENDERHANDLER_H
#define HANDLERS_RENDERHANDLER_H

// FW declaration of Game
class Game;

class RenderHandler {
    private:
        Game* game;

    public:
        RenderHandler() {};
        ~RenderHandler() {};

        void initialise(Game* game);
        void render();
}; // class RenderHandler
#endif // HANDLERS_RENDERHANDLER_H
```

Comment: Or, of course, the opposite and forward declare the `RenderHandler` class in `Game.h`. :)

Comment: @Joachim: Yeah, I would tend to think that what you propose would make more sense

Comment: but in doing this, will I still get access to functions in the declared class?

Comment: The proper way to do it is the following (taking my initial proposition as an example) : you FW declare `class Game` in the .h of `RenderHandler`, so you cannot access any functions of `Game` in code you would write in `RenderHandler.h`. However, in `RenderHandler.cpp` file you will include `Game.h` so you will have access to `Game` functions from there. If you are not using templates it is generally better to avoid writing any code in header files.